# Using debounceTime & distinctUntilChanged is not working when subscribing to FormBuilder valueChanges

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

very simply put, I want to perform a query after the user stops typing for a set amount of time. Every tutorial I've seen using `FormBuilder` suggests subscribing to `valueChanges` of the input field, while piping `debounceTime` and `distinctUntilChanged`.

```
this.threadForm.get('body').valueChanges.pipe(
            debounceTime(500),
            distinctUntilChanged(),
            mergeMap(search => this.db.query$(...)`))
      )
```

I cannot get this to work correctly. It appears to debounce the time properly, but when it gets piped through, it sends multiple of the final result (which distinctUntilChanged should handle). What am I doing wrong?

Here's a quick video of the problem (I added a `tap` so you can see that the webpage is logging several of the final result):

https://streamable.com/h2him

Thanks!

**EDIT: Adding surrounding code** the `source` function is run on each key click as well so I think that I'm instantiating multiple observables regardless of my debouncing. How can I add debounce logic within this?

```
  source: (searchTerm, renderList) => {
    //searchTerm is triggered on every button click
    if (searchTerm.length === 0) {
      renderList(this.mentions, searchTerm)
    } else {
      //are multiple instances of this observable being made??
      this.threadForm.get('body').valueChanges.pipe(
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        debounceTime(500),
        tap(x => console.log(x)),
        switchMap(search => this.db.query$(`user/collection?like=username_${searchTerm}&limit=5`))
      ).subscribe( x => {
        console.log(x)
      });
    }
  },
```

Comment: use `switchMap()` instead of `mergeMap()`

Comment: Also, invert your debounce and distinct for better performance

Comment: @xyz just attempted `switchMap`, with the same result :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i am pretty sure the issue here is related to the object that `valueChanges` emits. For the `distinctUntilChanged` the emitted object is different, you might want to map this object first to the value you actually need. (You can also hand a callback to [distinctUntilChanged](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged.html) to control what is meant to be distinct)

e.g.

```
this.threadForm.get('body').valueChanges.pipe(
  debounceTime(500),
  map( (obj) => obj.searchVal ),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  mergeMap(search => this.db.query$(...)`))
)
```

and you are most certainly looking for `switchMap` over `mergeMap`

**EDIT**

In order to work with the source function you can use a Subject like so.

```
var searchSubject = new Subject<any>();

source: (searchTerm, renderList) => {
  searchSubject.next({searchTerm, renderList});
}
```

than this `searchSubject` you subscribe only once in the `ngOnInit` and unsubscribe in `onDestroy` functions.

```
searchSubject.pipe(
 debounceTime(500),
 distinctUntilChanged(),
 mergeMap(search => this.db.query$(...)`))
)
```

Comment: so i think I discovered the issue but I am struggling to figure out how to resolve...wrapped around this observable is a function called `source` that is triggered on every letter that's typed as well, since the observable I posted in my question is inside, I think I'm instantiating multiple observables while typing thus even though I have debouncing etc it still returns multiple. I'll update my question so you can see the surrounding code, `searchTerm` is what is passed to inside to on every key press

Comment: you should not run this code on every keystroke, you need to create the observer once in the init function `ngOnInit()` and unsubscribe in the `ngDestroy()`, this way there is only one observable

Comment: I understand that, the `source` function comes from a library I'm using, which is why my question here was exactly what you were talking about haha, I want to use an observable but I need to have the observable inside that `source` function because I need to call a callback function from within that scope to trigger results to display

Comment: ah ok, i was confused with the threadFrom subscription, i thought you are using reactive forms. In the case the source is a fixed thing you can got with subjects i'll update my answer.

Comment: you are correct, I am using ReactiveForms :) I was attempting to use `valueChanges` from RF to detect when a certain time had passed, but the fact that every letter was triggering `source` and creating a new instance of my observable was messing everything up haha. looking forward to your update!

Comment: yeah you need to decide whether reactive forms with valueChanges or a callback function source style :)

Comment: wait okay all this makes sense, but with my `searchSubject` how do I call the callback function in `source` called `renderList` from outside that scope once I have my list of results from my query?

Comment: you can put it also in the observable if it is needed like `searchSub.next({searchTerm, renderList})` and convert the subject type from string to obj.

Comment: nailed it, thank you. I have so much to learn, thanks for putting me on the right track! :)

Comment: its a pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
this.threadForm.get('body').valueChanges.pipe(
  debounceTime(1000), 
  distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe(changes => {
  this.db.query$(...)
});
```