# Angular FormControl value changes triggers every change in formgroup

Tags: angular, form-control

I'm trying to make an api call to check the uniqueness of email of a user, but the problem is that the value changes triggers every change in all form controls.

here is my code :

```
Errors(){
  this.form01.valueChanges
    .subscribe((changedObj: any) => {
      this.valid = this.form01.valid;
      // Checks wether the email exists or not
      if (this.form01.get("email").valueChanges) {
        console.log("value of email changed");
      }
    });

}
```

My form Group :

```
// Form Group And It's Form Controls
  form01 = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    lastName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
    phone: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    roleID: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  });
```

My Inputs :

```
<form #addCityForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="create()" [formGroup]="form01">
    <div mat-dialog-content>
        <!-- First Name -->
        <p>
            <mat-form-field appearance="legacy">
                <mat-label>First Name</mat-label>
                <input matInput name="firstName" formControlName="firstName" [(ngModel)]="model.firstName" placeholder="First Name">
                <mat-error *ngIf="!valid">{{getError('firstName')}}</mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
        </p>

        <!-- Last Name -->
        <p>
            <mat-form-field appearance="legacy">
                <mat-label>Last Name</mat-label>
                <input matInput name="lastName" formControlName="lastName" [(ngModel)]="model.lastName" placeholder="Last Name"> 
                <mat-error *ngIf="!valid">{{getError('lastName')}}</mat-error>   
            </mat-form-field>
        </p>

        <!-- Email -->
        <p>
            <mat-form-field appearance="legacy">
                <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
                <input matInput name="email" formControlName="email" [(ngModel)]="model.email" placeholder="Email">  
                <mat-error *ngIf="!valid">{{getError('email')}}</mat-error>          
                <mat-hint class="validation-error" *ngIf="emailTaken">This Email is taken</mat-hint>  
                      
            </mat-form-field>
        </p>

        <!-- Phone -->
        <p>
            <mat-form-field appearance="legacy">
                <mat-label>Phone</mat-label>
                <input matInput name="phone" formControlName="phone" [(ngModel)]="model.phone" placeholder="Phone">
                <mat-error *ngIf="!valid">{{getError('phone')}}</mat-error>
                <mat-hint class="validation-error" *ngIf="phoneTaken">This Phone is taken</mat-hint>  
            </mat-form-field>
        </p>

        <!-- Role -->
        <p>
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
              <mat-label>Role</mat-label>
              <input name="roleID" type="text" placeholder="Role"
                  aria-label="Employee" matInput formControlName="roleID" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
                  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
                      <mat-option *ngFor="let role of roles" [value]="role.name" (click)="customRole(role.id)">
                          {{role.name}}
                      </mat-option>
                  </mat-autocomplete>
                 <mat-error *ngIf="!valid">{{getError('roleID')}}</mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
          </p>

        <!-- Password -->
        <p>
            <mat-form-field appearance="legacy">
                <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
                <input type="password" matInput name="password" formControlName="password" [(ngModel)]="model.password" placeholder="Password">
                <mat-error *ngIf="!valid">{{getError('password')}}</mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
        </p>

    </div>
    <div mat-dialog-actions>
        <button mat-dialog-close [mat-dialog-close]="model" [disabled]="!valid" mat-button type="submit">Save</button>
        <button mat-dialog-close mat-button type="button">Close</button>
    </div>
    
</form>
```

Here is the getError function

```
// Errors Messages
getError(field: string){
  if (this.form01.get(field).hasError('required')) {
    return "You must enter a value";
  }
  if (this.form01.get(field).hasError('email')) {
    return "Invalid Mail";
  }
}
```

The result when writing in firstName or lastName inputs :

```
value of email changed
```

I want the valuechanges to be triggered only when the email input is changed.
Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you need to subscribe to the `valueChange` of the email control, not the whole form.

Could be like this:

```
this.form01.get("email").valueChanges
  .subscribe((emailValue: string) => {
    // you have email value here
  });
```

BUT

There's an option of async validators for reactive forms. I think it would fit better for this situation. This way Angular will handle all errors and form states for you.

Also a tip, add a `debounceTime()` pipe with some delay so it doesn't send a request with every key stroke. This way you'll spare your back-end.

Docs: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#creating-asynchronous-validators

Comment: Thank you so much, in fact you are right, I was checking if an observable is true or false which is always true. 
and thank ou for debounceTime(), I was making a lot of times requests to the API before.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [get()](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/valuechanges-in-angular-forms/) function for that:

```
this.form01.get("email").valueChanges
    .subscribe(email => {
      console.log(email);
    });
```

Another way is to manually check the latest value:

```
lastEmail: string;

Error() {
  this.form01.valueChanges
    .subscribe(obj => {
        if (lastEmail !== obj?.email) {
            lastEmail = obj?.email;
            console.log(lastEmail);
        } 
    });
}
```

PS: You should consider that calling a api call on every new value, may bring problems because multiple api calls may happen.

I advice you to limit the api calls using the distinct latest value, some seconds after the last change.

You can see the [relative thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55609949/6442841).

Comment: The message that is logging is from the get("email"), this is quite the problem in fact, even when I'm using the get method, the message gets logged for every change on every input.

Comment: What `getError` does? Maybe the problem is there...

Comment: I've added the code for getError in the post ! thank you

Comment: I don't know why this is happening but I updated my answer with a hack :/

Comment: In fact your answer is also right, I didn't notice that you subscribed to the valuechanges observable also

Comment: Yes was correct and 5 minutes earlier from the accepted one with the same observation about debouncing and +1, a hack :D. Nevermind, I'm glad you found the way :)

Comment: I'm really sorry but the other guy gave the answer before your edit :/ , and his answer was more specific, you told me to use get in the first place which I was already using. Anyway thank you so much for your help, if I had to add a new answer to this question It would absolutely be yours.